# Convert a webforms project to a hybrid MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

At the moment, we have an old style ASP.NET project that has around 800 .aspx pages.

We are looking at migrating this from ASP.NET webforms to MVC4 + Razor over time, but do not want to have to scrap the entire project and start again.

Is it possible to convert the project file to an MVC project and add the required files/folders for the project to run as an MVC project, but at the same time, preserving the original file/folder structure allowing the existing/legacy pages to still be accessed in the same way as they are now accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check below links:

http://rachelappel.com/integrating-aspnet-web-forms-and-aspnetmvc

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/integratingaspnetmvc3intoexistingupgradedaspnet4webformsapplications.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to convert the project file to an MVC project and add
>   the required files/folders for the project to run as an MVC project

Based on my experience with a Web Application project on VS2012 featuring several hundred .aspx, it is definitely possible to have webforms and mvc 4 with razor running in the same application.

We did not modify the project file (more on that later). We started from a bare MVC4 application and copied the needed features in our webforms application. This included :

- packages and references
- directives in the web.config (as far as I remember : extensionless handlers, system.web.webPages.razor element, and some assembly bindings )
- most of the global.asax mechanisms ( namely routing for a bare application)
- directory structure (models, views and controllers)

This was a tedious work, but it also helped us understand what makes an MVC project work. We still miss some IDE features like not having MVC components (views, controllers) offered when right-click -> Add... I guess this would require a csproj editing. We did not go that far.

To prevent conflicting urls, MVC is used through several dedicated areas which would, in the end, replace the corresponding webforms folders.