# Is it possible to convert Asp.net Webform to MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in Asp.net webform and now we are looking to move it to MVC. Is it possible to convert the project or we have to create the project form the scratch?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'not easily or automatically', and the typical business decision is that the effort involved compared to the return on investment makes it not worthwhile to do so.

However, some colleagues of mine have implemented Web Forms MVP, which is a [Model-View-Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) framework for ASP.NET Web Forms. This will faciliate a MVC-like design pattern but inside existing Web Forms projects. It is available for free on GitHub:
https://github.com/webformsmvp/webformsmvp

You can also run Web Forms and MVC side-by-side if need be:
[Convert a webforms project to a hybrid MVC4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635794/convert-a-webforms-project-to-a-hybrid-mvc4-project)

Comment: Hybrid application can be a solution. Also we are looking to use  the DAL and BAl of the previous Applications allowing us to create only the presentation and controllers. Please provide your  suggestion on this.

Comment: My suggestion was to use Web Forms MVP :) But it sounds like you know what you want to do with the hybrid solution. Good luck!